# How to group and printing unique values of Column-B wrt to Column-A in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Sample data:

```
tz = ["us","eu","ca","de","us","eu","ca","us","eu"]
ip = ["2.3.3.1","2.3.3.1","2.3.3.1","2.3.3.1","2.3.3.1","5.3.3.1","2.3.3.1","4.3.3.1","2.3.3.1"]
val = ["2.3","2.3","2.3","2.3","2.3","2.3","2.3","2.3","2.3"]
r = pd.DataFrame({'tz':tz,'ip':ip,'val':val})
r
r.groupby(tz).describe()
```

I would like to have my result printed as:

```
ca --> 2.3.3.1
de --> 2.3.3.1
eu --> 2.3.3.1, 5.3.3.1 
us --> 2.3.3.1, 4.3.3.1
```

Answer (score 2):

`unique` works:

```
>>> u = r.groupby(tz)['ip'].unique()
>>> for i in u.index:
        print(i, '-->', ', '.join(u[i]))

ca --> 2.3.3.1
de --> 2.3.3.1
eu --> 2.3.3.1, 5.3.3.1
us --> 2.3.3.1, 4.3.3.1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
timezones = r['tz'].unique()

for timezone in timezones:
    print timezone + "  --->  " + ", ".join([i for i in list(r[r['tz']==timezone]['ip'].unique()])
```

This will literally print it out as requested... although should be straight forward to adapt this to capture a list etc.

Comment: thanks @jprockbelly. I was wondering if their was a pandas way/function of selecting and printing it, but this will work as well.

Comment: Turns out Mike Müller has a more 'pandonic' way :)